# Checking if a prop value exists in JSON payload

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm writing a Jest test to check if  `<Demo payload={jsonpayload} Value="Item 1" />` `value` exists in the payload.

This is how my test file looks:

```
const payload= [
    {
        ItemName: "Item 1"
    },
    {
        ItemName: "Item 2"
    },
    {
        ItemName: "Item 3"
    },
]

it("Has a value from one of the itmes in the json payload", () => {
        const dropdown = enzyme.mount(<Dropdown {...DEMO_PROPS} />);
        const value = dropdown.props().Value;
        expect(payload.map(item => item.ItemName)).toEqual(value);
    });
```

I know my test is wrong because this returns all the items in payload. I simply want to test if `value` exists in the payload or not.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How about `expect(payload.filter(item => item.ItemName === value).length > 0).toEqual(true)` ?

Comment: Small note, the payload const defined is not JSON but JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Use `some` instead of `map`

> some() executes the callback function once for each element present in
>   the array until it finds one where callback returns a truthy value (a
>   value that becomes true when converted to a Boolean). If such an
>   element is found, some() immediately returns true. Otherwise, some()
>   returns false.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

```
const hasItem = payload.some(item => item.ItemName == value);
expect(hasItem).toBe(true);
```